# Desktop background on start does not work in Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried to set the start screen background to the same as the wallpaper, but the option is greyed out on the Navigation tab.

[image]

Comment: I have done it using this guide: http://techzend.com/same-image-start-screen-desktop-windows-81/ and your Windows is not activated.. Leave a ticket on the contact page of MS.

Comment: @ben It is activated.

Answer (score 2):

This functions only works when Windows is activated.

Comment: -1 My Windows **is** activated.

Comment: is the Desktop Experience Role/Feature installed?

Comment: Yes. 

Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: there are 3 thing which must be true, otherwise you can't change it: this 2 policies must be false: NoChangingStartMenuBackground, ForceStartBackground and Windows must be activated. Win8.1/2012R2 check this in this function: CImmersiveLauncherApps::_CanChangeAccent

Comment: I set this policy and still i can’t get the top section in “Personalise” to show.

Comment: enabling them prevents you to set the picture.

Comment: Tried all combinations of them and still the option is disabled.

Comment: in this case I'm out of ideas. Phone the MS support.

Comment: do you have email support? Also try to contact the English (EN-GB) support.

Comment: also, try all steps from here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-my-desktop-background-on-start-greyed-out-in-windows